# Cannot see Nexus 5X from android studio on mac

Tags: macos, android-studio

I cannot see my Nexus 5X `Android 6.0` on Android Studio **Device Chooser** on my Mac.

But the device is connected to the Mac,

```
macbook-pro-de-mincong:~ minconghuang$ system_profiler SPUSBDataType
USB:

    USB 3.0 Bus:

      Capacity: 63.3 MB (63,292,320 bytes)
      ...

        Nexus 5X:

          Product ID: ...
          Vendor ID: ...  (Google Inc.)
          Version: 3.10
          Serial Number: ...
          Speed: Up to 480 Mb/sec
          Manufacturer: LGE
          Location ID: ... / 26
          Current Available (mA): 1000
          Current Required (mA): 500
          Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

However, the android studio do work with another Android device running `Android 4.4.4 API 19`. Recognition within 1s. So where might the problem come from ? By the way, the Nexus 5X uses usb-c connector and I use an adaptor usb-c/use-a. I don't know whether it causes problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the mechanism, but when i restart my Mac, it works. (I didn't reboot since 3 weeks..)